# Power Supply may be going out

Tags: video, power-supply, blank-screen

Could a screen go black after boot up or near boot-up due to the case Power Supply not putting out enough juice to run the computer when the OS comes on?

Comment: Test with a different video card if you can. You might also look at getting a PSU tester as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your theory by unplugging a few devices and see if you successfully boot.

Remove power from optical drive (s), remove expansion cards (like video and sound if you have them).

Is the machine itself actually shutting down/restarting? Have you ruled out the monitor being faulty?

Comment: I guess I could hook original monitor to another computer and the origial computer to another monitor, as see if it replicates on either way.  I was just wondering as I had an old HP where this happened and I replaced the P/S and everythiong was OK.  Process of elimintion, I guess.  Thanks!!!